# How to get the name of the active file in Atom?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I want to get the name of the current file in a package for Atom 1.0. I know how to get the full path to the file, but I would like to only get the file name part of the path. This is the code I have so far (taken from [atom-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal)):

```
editor = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem()
file = editor?.buffer?.file
filepath = file?.path
```

I tried to read though the docs to see if such an attribute already exists, but the Pane items are not documented as far as I could find. Is there documentation available somewhere else than at https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.0?

If there isn't an attribute, is there an appropriate standard function for extracting the file part of the path from `filepath` in a platform independant way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method provided by @jacwah is no longer working in atom 1.18. According to the [API docs](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.17.0/TextEditor#instance-getPath) you can get path using the following code:

```
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.getPath()
```

Comment: getBaseName is still valid, but not on the editor. @jacwah mentioned this function on the editor.buffer.file object. The way to access the editor has changed, no the file object. `atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().buffer.file.getBaseName()` works perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the `?` doing in the code? I get an error if I include it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `file.getBaseName()`. This will return only the filename part of the path to `file`. I found this by logging the file to the console and examining it's properties.

```
editor = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem()
file = editor?.buffer?.file
filename = file?.getBaseName()
```

You can also use the node.js `path` module's `basename` function.

```
path = require('path')

editor = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem()
file = editor?.buffer?.file
filename = path.basename(file?.path)
```

Answer (score -1):

use .getTitle():

```
atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.getTitle()
```

Comment: This probably works, but what if the user customizes this or actually saves a file named "untitled"? `getPath` seems more apt.